# Missing Pin Options from Bluetooth Pairing GUI

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, gui

I am trying to pair a Bluetooth module (RN-41 serial port) to my Ubuntu machine using the provided GUI in System Settings. I've successfully paired using the console but for whatever reason I cannot do this through the GUI as dumb as that seems. Here is what I can select from using the GUI for Pin Options:

[image: Missing option screen shot]

While I've found a previous answer with the complete set of options:

[image: Complete option screen shot]

The whole reason I even care about this is because I have a device with a fixed pin of 1234 and because my only option under Fixed Pin is "Do Not Pair"... well I really have no options then. Anyway, suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Please see comment below for bug report link because at the time of writing I do not have enough rep to add another link

Comment: Here's the bug report link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-bluetooth/+bug/551950

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything with PIN options in 16.04 as it should figure the PIN out on its own for a mouse.  It worked like that for me when pairing my Logitech travel mouse

You could edit /usr/share/gnome-bluetooth/pin-code-database.xml and add a line as a work around

`<device oui="00:1B:C1:" name="HOLUX_M-241" pin="0000"/>`

Change the 00:1B:C1 to match the first part of your devices MAC address.  Change HOLUX_M-241 to match your devices name and do the same for the pin.  Make the line match the others indentation, save and reboot

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't for a mouse, it's for a RN41 Bluetooth module which has a serial port profile by default. I'll update that part of the question. I'm more asking if anyone has seen a bug in the system settings like this before and if there's a way to fix it.

Comment: It should work for anything with a fixed pin, headphones, mouse, portable speakers

Comment: My problem is that my system GUI is only showing 2 options in the top picture: Automatic PIN or Do Not Pair. Obviously Do Not Pair is not what I would want because I'm trying to pair the device and Automatic selects a random PIN which causes the pair to fail because the device uses a fixed one.

Like I said, I'm able to pair and connect to devices with fixed pins through the command line and posted this to see if anyone has run into this problem with the system GUI.

Comment: File a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug) against package gnome-bluetooth for not being able to use a custom PIN

Comment: The Gnome bug you found isn't relevant as that user could enter the PIN, you need to file a bug with Ubuntu at launchpad as Ubuntu has been known to make some custom patches

Comment: This workaround doesn't quite fix everything for me. The system still wants to use a random pin sometimes. Here's the link for the appropriate bug report for future use: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-bluetooth/+bug/551950